# Is it possible to create agents via the API?

Tags: dialogflow-es

So I've been reviewing the DialogFlow [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/) and wondering if it's possible to use the API fully programmatically and create agents via the API as well? A sample use case being the user on my platform being to able to create **their own bot**. I'm not able to find the functionality listed in their docs and wanted to double check with the community here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t create an agent through the API but once it’s been created in the UI it can be edited through the API.  Users will need to grant your service account the dialogflow editor IAM role and then tell you their project ID.

Comment: Any idea why it is this way? It's kind of very limiting.

Answer (score 3):

You can now create and update agents with the API. See the [REST](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects) and [RPC](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Agents.SetAgent) documentation.